# __setattr__ vs class properties to set attributes

Tags: python, class, methods

Consider the two following class definitions in which, in order to do additional checks before assigning a value to an attribute (e.g., keep track of modified variables, check for validity, etc.) in the first one I override the `__setattr__` method  and in the second one I use properties.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # do something
        self.__dict__[name] = value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        # do something
        self.x = v
```

To me, it looks like they behave at the same way.
Is there any difference between the two? Which one should be preferred and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__setattr__` is more general, as it will run for `A().foo = 3`, no matter what attribute `foo` you provide. Property setters are specific to a single, explicitly defined property, and can't be used to "accidentally" create an attribute.